# Can a post request be sent via a button without a wrapping form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the user reaction to a post thingy am working on.

it consist of

```
<button name="like" data-post-id="123">like</button>

<button name="dislike" data-post-id="123">dislike</button>

<button name="not bad" data-post-id="123">not bad</button>

<button name="crazy!" data-post-id="123">crazy!</button>
```

is there any way to submit this with out individually wrapping the buttons in a form?

Comment: you could use javascript and ajax to send a behind-the-scense post or get to a php script

Answer (score 2):

You can bind an event listener to your buttons and use AJAX to handle the request.

Example using jQuery:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var id = $(this).attr('data-post-id');

    $.post( "/path/to/file", { name: name, id: id }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    } );
})
```

Comment: Note: You do not need jQuery or any other libraries to send ajax requests.

Comment: Yes - i understand that, jquery just makes it easier.